# Load Resources form static base even wit Mod_Rewrite

Tags: php, html

I want to use mod_rewrite to make my urls make seo conform.

So if I use http://localhost/webinterface/index.php?section=spieleliste everything works fine.
If I use http://localhost/webinterface/features/spieleliste/ he does not load my Resources.

The Resources are located at http://localhost/webinterface/theme/css/global.css but he trys to get them from http://localhost/webinterface/features/spieleliste/theme/css/global.css.

My .htacces file

```
RewriteRule ^features/spieleliste$ index.php?section=spieleliste
```

Comment: I'm guessing your HTML `<link ... />` tag looks something like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="theme/css/global.css" />` using a relative URL rather than an URL that's either absolute or relative to the document root, e.g.: `/theme/css/global.css` ?

Comment: Yes that is right but I also do use
`<base href="localhost">`

Comment: That should probably be `<base href="http://localhost/" />` as it's supposed to be an absolute URL. Personally I wouldn't bother with the base href and would just use URLs relative to the docroot; it would only mean adding an additional `/`

Comment: Where do I have to add the `/`

Comment: It would be an additional `/` on each URL so instead of `theme/css/global.css` it's `/theme/css/global.css` - it'll save you headaches in the long run moving between dev and live servers or when using URL fragments ([see the Hint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base))